# python ./store/manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

`python ./store/manage.py runserver` when I ran this I got error like this:

```
$  python ./store/manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000003AE6978>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py2.7.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named polls
```

Comment: Why are you running from the parent directory, instead of inside store?

Comment: what is the file structure of your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested some cases and the only one where I got the same error is when I added an app that does not exist in my project to my `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` file. So, make sure that you have created `polls` app using `python manage.py startapp polls` (you should have `/store/polls` folder).

To create `polls` app if it does not exist, you will need first to remove it from your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Without removing it first, you will get the same error as above.

Furthermore, you need to cd  to your project root folder before running any command (even if it is not required for the above command), so instead of:

```
python ./store/manage.py runserver
```

Run:

```
cd store/
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: i created store in desktop as django-admin startproject store in directory C:\Users\tulasi\desktop and then after i add the python manage.py startapp polls in same above directory (i.e C:\users\tulasi\desktop) is it correct

Comment: thanks alot ...... i instead of inside  store i created seperately .now i got once again thank you very much

Comment: No it is not correct. You should first enter to polls directory like I said in my answer.  Move your polls folder to store/ and try to start your server.

Comment: @tulasiram You're welcome, you can accept my answer :)

Comment: when i type python manage.py shell and output is displaying nothing and i did all migrations.first when i run i got a shell prompt and after closing gitbash and again when i run this no shell prompt is coming

Comment: If the above question is answered and that issue is solved then you need to ask another question for this second issue.